# Newly opened applications always default to HDMI sound output (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

When changing the sound output device to my headphones instead of HDMI in GNOME settings, it only seems to change the output for applications that are currently playing audio. If I were to close the application and re-open it, for example, it defaults to using HDMI instead of headphones.

I've installed `pavucontrol` which allows me to change the output device for specific applications, but I want to have newly opened applications to default to the headphones that I had set in the GNOME settings panel (having to switch the audio device on every opened application from HDMI to headphones is extremely bothersome).

Here's an example of what I mean. Take note that the output device in gnome is set as Headphones, but upon opening spotify and playing music, that specific application defaults to HDMI output (This happens with every application and is not specific to spotify).
[image: Example]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report on this:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/749

I have no problem on my Ubuntu 20.10 system, but there is a suggested fix

Use `sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`

or use
`sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`

and find the lines:

```
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Change them to:

```
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
#load-module module-switch-on-connect
```